# Upload and Parse multiple JSON files in javascript and vuejs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to upload and save multiple JSON files.
previously for uploading and saving a single JSON file I was doing this:

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="fileSelect" class="custom-file-input" @change="showfiles" />
```

```
showfiles() {
        let files = (this.$refs.fileSelect as HTMLInputElement).files
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => { this.data = JSON.parse(reader.result as string); }
        reader.readAsText(files![0]);
    }
```

I was saving the json file in `this.data`

Now I want to upload and save multiple JSON files similarly and save them in `this.data`
So I updated the above code as follows (I thought I can loop and append the file data):

```
<input multiple type="file" id="file" ref="fileSelect" class="custom-file-input" @change="showfiles" />
```

```
showfiles() {
        let files = (this.$refs.fileSelect as HTMLInputElement).files
        
        for(let i=0;i<files!.length;i++){   
          var reader = new FileReader();       
          reader.onload = () => { this.data[i] = JSON.parse(reader.result as string); }
          reader.readAsText(files![i]);}

    }
```

But this is not working as intended, it is only appending the file selected last multiple times (and the 0th index is null, so for example if I select `file1.json , file2.json, file3.json` in `this.data` `0 is null and 1,2 index are data from file3.json`.
What am I doing wrong?

My current complete code:

```
<input multiple type="file" id="file" ref="fileSelect" class="custom-file-input" @change="showfiles" />  
<script lang='ts'>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HomeView',
  props: [],
  data(){
    return{
      data:{}
      
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showfiles() {
      this.data={}
      let files = (this.$refs.fileSelect as HTMLInputElement).files
         
       for(let i=0;i<files!.length;i++){       
           var reader = new FileReader();     
           reader.onload = () => { this.data[i] = JSON.parse(reader.result as string);}
           reader.readAsText(files![i]);
          }
   }
```

Comment: shouldn't you first initialize this.data to be an empty array?

Comment: I have already done that, I didn;t show it here.
Do you mean inside ```showfiles()``` ?

Comment: If you create a complete snippet of code that runs you'll be more likely to receive help.

Comment: I have edited and added my complete code snippet now, please let me know if you figure out what I am doing incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing Vue or TypeScript specific in your question, so I'll attempt to answer with plain old JavaScript.  I've included a runnable code snippet.

In a nutshell, whenever the selected files change:

- Create a single `FileReader` instead of one per selected file.
- Attach a single `load` event listener, and obtain the `FileReader`'s `result` (the file content).
- Read each file, one at a time, waiting for each file to be loaded and read prior to reading the next file.

Were it me, I would make a function to read a file and resolve with the file's content.  You could then call that function from your `showFiles` method, and `await` the result of each file.

Here's a runnable example in raw JavaScript.  Note that `inputFile` corresponds to your `fileSelect` reference, and the `results` array corresponds to your `data` array (which, BTW, should be an array not an object).  Also, I've wired up the `change` event listener in the JS code, but it's the same as the `@change` listener in your template.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  const inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile')

  // Holds the contents of each selected file.
  const results = []

  inputFile.addEventListener('change', async e => {
    const files  = e.target.files
    const reader = new FileReader()

    // New set of results each time.
    results.splice(0)

    for (const file of files)
      results.push(await readFile(reader, file))

    // Do something with the files.
    console.log(results)
  })

  /**
   * Read a file asynchronously and resolve with the contents.
   * 
   * @param {FileReader} reader - A FileReader instance that will read `file`
   * as text.
   * @param {File} file - A selected File instance.
   */
  function readFile(reader, file) {
    const deferredResult = new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.addEventListener('load', function getResult() {
        resolve(reader.result)
        reader.removeEventListener('load', getResult)
      })
    })

    reader.readAsText(file)

    return deferredResult
  }
})()
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input multiple type="file" id="inputFile" accept=".json">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the reason I mentioned Typescript and Vue is because I am new to both and I wasn't sure that my code a syntax problem or something else.

One thing, I was able to convert your answer and use it in my Vue code https://jsfiddle.net/Harsh2207/3xmh86pd/9/#&togetherjs=zuB1Iq8zTn
The only problem I am facing is upload, the ```addEventListener``` is not working properly I think, cause I had to create a button that starts the function then when I upload the files, it reads them. Do you why that might be?

Comment: In your original code you have a `@change` handler on the input.  Use that instead of `addEventListener('change', ...)`.  You also used a `ref` on the input: use that instead of `document.getElementById`.

Comment: what should I put instead of ```addEventListener('change', ...)``` , I removed it but now I get an error that ```inputFile is not callable```.